# How to increase the number of entries a jquery DataTable displays?

Tags: php, jquery, phpmyadmin, datatables

I have a database with 18000 rows.
The DataTable is displaying the first 500 rows.

How do I increase the number of entries it can display?

`pageLength` & `lengthMenu` properties don't affect the result.

**game_db.php**

```
<?php
function getGames() { 
    $query = "select * FROM games LIMIT 10000"; 
    try {
    global $db;
        $games = $db->query($query);  
        $game = $games->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
        echo '{"games": ' . json_encode($game) . '}';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
?>
```

**main.js**

```
function renderList(data){
    list = data.games;
    console.log("renderList");
    $('#admin_table_body tr').remove();
    $.each(list, function(index, games){
        $('#admin_table_body').append('<tr><td>' +games.title+'</td><td>'+games.genre+'</td><td>' 
                +games.platform+'</td><td>' +games.score_phrase+'</td><td>'
                +games.score+'</td><td>'+games.release_year+'</td><td>'+games.release_month+'</td><td>'
                +games.release_day+'</td><td>'+games.editors_choice+'</td><td>\n\
                <a href="#"  id="'+games.id+'" "span class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</a></td></tr>');
    });
    $('#admin_table').DataTable();
```

This generates the rows in the datatable.

Comment: Can you try to create a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you show the code here

Comment: kindly show code or share fiddle

Comment: You need to show us your entire code. Paste it in your question.

Comment: Apologies for lack of info. If the LIMIT in the query is not set to >= 500 then no data gets displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Use iDisplayLength parameter

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": 1000 // to display 1000 rows
    "iDisplayLength": -1 // to display all rows
  } );
} )
```

https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#iDisplayLength

Comment: $('#admin_table').DataTable({"iDisplayLength": -1});

If I use 'DisplayLength', it will show 500/500 entries in one page.
I'm trying to increase the number of entries it displays to 18000.

Could it be a problem server-side?

I'm using phpMyAdmin

Comment: yes. May be you are retrieving only 500 rows from database. check your query.

Comment: My query limits it to 500 rows. 
Stupidly overlooked...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I remember, I set the limit to 500 because anything greater than this number will cause my table to not display at all

Comment: If you are getting only 500 records from database,  how can you display 18000 rows in datatables.

Comment: The datatable does not display at all if I remove the LIMIT.

Comment: Do you see any datatable error if limit is removed ?. If records are more datatable takes some time to display them.

Comment: There is no error. The column names appear but not in datatable format.

Comment: Check data in the database. My be some special characters causing the issue.

Comment: You should avoid using [legacy version of datatables](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not using DataTables properly. You are creating table without the help of DataTables library. That is the reason why [`pageLength`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) & [`lengthMenu`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) options are not working.

```
$('#admin_table_body').append('<tr><td>' +games.title+'</td><td>'+games.genre+'</td><td>' 
          +games.platform+'</td><td>' +games.score_phrase+'</td><td>'
          +games.score+'</td><td>'+games.release_year+'</td><td>'+games.release_month+'</td><td>'
          +games.release_day+'</td><td>'+games.editors_choice+'</td><td>
          <a href="#"  id="'+games.id+'" "span class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</a></td></tr>');
```

Instead you should use like this below. See [DataTables Ajax sourced data doc](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) for more details.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "path/of/your/php_file.php"
} );
```

Now you can use [`pageLength`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) options. Keep in mind that if `pagination` is disabled using the [`paging`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging) option, this option is automatically disabled since it has no relevance when there is no pagination.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "path/of/your/php_file.php",
    "pageLength": 700
} );
```

I'll suggest you against of increasing [`pageLength`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength) in favour of performance. See [this thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24037/what-is-the-limit-of-records-we-can-deal-with) for more information.

[Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/A1CtSa6XzTxhn90x9rh0/)

Comment: I set up the datatable like you specified. However, if I remove the limit 500 in the query then the 'getGames()' function returns invalid JSON. 

The response is ' {"games": } '

If the limit is put back into the query, then the response is valid JSON.
I don't understand why this is happening...

Comment: I'll suggest you to copy that json and paste it in [online json validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to check whether it is valid or not.